# Hangman Java Programming

Tags: java

I'm a beginner student at learning Java.
I'm supposed to be making a Hangman game. I have the first option ready but I have very little to no clue on how to make it. I need help with creating a list and allowing the computer to choose a word from the list to let the user play. My code is below and I will go forth with finishing it once I achieve an answer.
 I would also like to know how to subtract said "Body parts"  from the Hangedman I have drawn below. 
Thank you for your time. :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Hangman
{
  public static void main (String[]args)
  {
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


     String gameMode = "";


     int option = 3;
     while(option != 0);
    { 
      System.err.println("\n H A N G M A N");
      System.out.println(" \n \n Lets play Hangman!");
      System.out.println("\n Choose a game mode to play");
      System.err.println("Options: ");
      System.out.println("\n(1) Select to play against computer");
      System.out.println("\n(3) Select to terminate program");
      System.out.println("\n \n  ___________.._______");
      System.err.println("| | / /      ||");
      System.err.println("| |/ /       ||");
      System.err.println("| | /        ||.-''-.");
      System.err.println("| |/         |/  _ _|  "); 
      System.err.println("| |          ||  '\'|");
      System.err.println("| |          (\\ _O/'");
      System.err.println("| |         .-'--'-.");
      System.err.println("| |        / Y. .Y||  ");
      System.err.println("| |       // |   |||  ");
      System.err.println("| |      //  | . ||| ");
      System.err.println("| |    ( '') |   |('') ");
      System.err.println("| |          ||- ||");
      System.err.println("| |          || ||");
      System.err.println("| |          || ||");
      System.err.println("| |          || ||");
      System.err.println("| |         / | | \\");
      System.err.println(" ''''''''''|_`-' `-' |''''| ");
      System.out.println(" |'|'''''''\\''''''''|'| ");
      System.out.println(" | |        \\        | | ");
      System.out.println(" : :         \\       : :  ");
      System.out.println(" . .          `'       . .");


      option = sc.nextInt();

      sc.nextLine();


      if(option == 1)
    {
         while(true)
         {
         System.out.println("I will generate a random word for you to play. So expect the unexpected");
         gameMode = sc.nextInt();
 if(gameMode != 1 )
  {
{
System.out.println("Invalid input please re-enter information with no spaces, numbers or capitals.");
    }
     break;}
        }
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: well you can put your words in array or ArrayList, and select them using Random.nextInt()

Comment: You do not subtract body parts, you simply redraw different images.

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example? Maybe a reference site ? If it's not too much trouble?

Comment: How would I make it redraw the images differently due to each incorrect word?

Comment: Why don't simplify it and avoid drawing it at all. Just have a statement which prints to the console like "Right arm gone, 5 body parts left" or something like that?

Comment: In a terminal application either a) you draw the new picture underneath the previous one (by means of carriage returns / line feeds) or b) you send terminal commands to clear the screen and redraw (but that makes it OS-specific).

Comment: If I was assigned such a task I would rather spend time on the actual logic rather than on drawing an ascii hangman. I mean, basically you could just go with a limited amount of "wrong guesses" that you decrement...

Comment: @Bartdude don't be so harsh, the guy clearly has an artistic spirit! :)

Comment: @AlessandroSantini Thanks :D I am an art student but no so good at code... So I'm very confused right now.

Comment: Since you are a student... We cant give you all the good stuff until you learned them. What have you learned so far? Arrays, ArrayList?. You could make arrays of array of hangman images and then call the right one for every wrong guess.

Comment: Erhm... I still don't know how to do it. @MightyPork can you give me an example?

Comment: I've only learned Arrays, sir.The simple number ones only. @DaveP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array only ok

```
String[][] hangnanImages = {{"| | / /      ||",
                             "| |/ /       ||",
                             "| | /        ||.-''-.",
                             "| |/         |/  _ _|",
                             "| |          ||  '\'|",
                             "| |          (\\ _O/'",
                             "| |         .-'--'-.",
                             "| |        / Y. .Y||  ",
                             "| |       // |   |||  ",
                             "| |      //  | . ||| ",
                             "| |    ( '') |   |('') ",
                             "| |          ||- ||",
                             "| |          || ||",
                             "| |          || ||",
                             "| |          || ||",
                             "| |         / | | \\",
                             " ''''''''''|_`-' `-' |''''|"},
                            {"| | / /      ||",
                             "| |/ /       ||",
                             "| | /        ||.-''-.",
                             "| |/         |/  _ _|",
                             "| |          ||  '\'|",
                             "| |          (\\ _O/'",
                             "| |         .-'--'-.",
                             "| |          Y. .Y||  ",
                             "| |          |   |||  ",
                             "| |          | . ||| ",
                             "| |          |   |('') ",
                             "| |          ||- ||",
                             "| |          || ||",
                             "| |          || ||",
                             "| |          || ||",
                             "| |         / | | \\",
                             " ''''''''''|_`-' `-' |''''|"}};//Put next hang man image in this one and similar and make as many as u want to your liking.
```

then what u can do you can make a method something like getHangmanImage(int num)

```
public String[] getHangmanImage(int number){
    return hangManImages[number]; //this will return only a String[] not String[][] 
}
//alternatively you can just do 
public void printHangman(int number){
    for(int i = 0; i < hangmanImages[number].length; i++){
        System.err.println(hangmanImages[number][i]);
    }
}
```

Now for the part MightyPork was talking about was this

```
String[] words = {"Word", "Components", ect ect}//however you want to put words in here.
Random rnd = new Random();

String rndWord = words[rnd.nextInt(words.length)];
```

Comment: I coded this on the fly. What part are you having issues with?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used java in a while, but let me see if i can help.

**First you need to call the file:**
    File words = new File("listedWords.txt");
    Scanner FileScanner = new Scanner(File);
**Second you need to run a loop to output that list:**
    while(FileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
       int i = FileScanner.nextInt();
       System.out.println(i);
    }

Hopefully the syntax is right and that gets you started. After these two things its a simple input to get a string of one of the words

Comment: You are assuming hes going to use a file. But yeah this is one way to go.

Comment: when i hear list i think file haha sorry